# Remove BasicTextField Indicator Bulb in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Im not sure what this is called so I call it a indicator bulb, its the image thats hanging off of the indicator. It appears above my bottom modal and I think that looks funky, how do we remove this?

[image: image with indicator bulb]

[image: Image with bulb over the bottom sheet]

Comment: The component is called `TextFieldCursorHandle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the cursor using `cursorBrush = SolidColor(Unspecified)`.

You have also to define a custom `TextSelectionColors` to override the default color provided by `LocalTextSelectionColors.current` that it is applied to the text selection and the `TextFieldCursorHandle`.

```
val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = Color.Transparent,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
)

CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
   BasicTextField(
       value = text,
       onValueChange = {text = it},
       cursorBrush = SolidColor(Unspecified)
   )
}
```